# What's Evasive Fire's threshold range?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-demon-hunter

I've been using [Evasive Fire](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/class/demon-hunter/active/evasive-fire) and [Steady Aim](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/class/demon-hunter/passive/steady-aim), and I've been wondering - if Evasive Fire doesn't trigger, does it mean Steady Aim applies?

Or more generally, what's the maximum range to the monster being shot for Evasive Fire to perform a backflip?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After using it a lot, and using [this chart](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/66058/122) as a guideline, I think the threshold is around 15 yards.

In any case I'm confident it's more than 10 yards, meaning that if Evasive Fire doesn't trigger, Steady Aim does indeed apply.