# How large is a Smite Arena map in units?

Tags: smite

I'm trying to get a frame of reference for just how big maps are. The *Through Space and Time* power will cast portals through any surface *"within range 500"*, and then does 200% magical power as damage *"at distances greater than 800"*.

What sort of distance does this 'range' actually cover however? **How many "range units" is it from edge to edge in an Arena map, for example?**

The Arena map is a familiar size for me compared to the jungle/lane maps. I'm trying to get a sense of what these distances are to help quickly eyeball ranges of powers in general (like Ratatoskr's tree-branch jump-move thing), and also to get a frame of reference for distances in Smite in general.

*[Same question asked here](https://m.reddit.com/r/Smite/comments/2arb6j/can_we_see_units_in_metric_as_well/), so I know I'm not the only one who wants to know this.*

Comment: why do you need to know this?

Comment: @Rapitor I'm curious because Janus has a power that shoots portals 500 units, then grows in damage until 800 units. wondering if that covers a conquest map titan to titan, or just an arena map base to base? i have no perspective really on the distances

Comment: A better question to ask, then, would be how far those distances are.  Asking how large the map is isn't extremely useful at all, but asking how far a power goes is very useful.

Comment: id like a yardstick for general distances in the game. A better question would be "how big is a unit" but the answer would be "one". so im looking for a way to conceptualize how far 500/800 units (for example) looks like. its useful information to me.

Comment: I would envision something like [this question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/66055/how-far-is-a-yard-on-screen) would be immensely helpful.

Comment: no @Frank, thats not immensely helpful. im talking about distances from 500 to 1000 units to estimate. so one yard isnt a good measuring stick for estimation. go answer another question if you dont think this one is useful to you.

Comment: @Dpeif The system here is designed to [allow others to edit your posts](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/editing) (much like Wikipedia).

Comment: yes i am familiar with the stack exchange policies. but the edits didnt clarify or improve the question, they changed the parameters of the requested answer. that's not appropriate. as you can see, my question does have an answer, which was easily attainable after the suggestion of using the spell cast ruler, and answers a related question over on Reddit, so its obviously info that others would appreciate.

Comment: Well, I was pointing at it as an example, for you to base your question as, but sure, let's just discard me trying to be helpful to you and everyone else around.

Comment: @Frank: If someone had an image like that accepted Diablo answer, except for every single map type in Smite (in "units" of course), that'd be an *amazing* answer. I just don't think it's feasible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I only asked this question because I thought someone would know a definitive answer, or a way to find out. I used the spell-cast ruler (activated in casting options) to manually eyeball the Arena map.

The ruler is 70 units long. I measured the arena straight down the middle. The arena base, from wall to portal, is about 70 units. Then its about 70 from the portal to the first column, 70 from first column to second column, and then the middle of the arena is about 70 units across. So, it ends up being about ~500 units from wall to wall, measured through the center of the map (70+70+70+70+70+70+70=490).

So, to return to my earlier example, Janus's power Through Space and Time would cast portals the whole length of an arena map, but would never get near the 800 unit damage cap.