# What is the maximum distance for Janus's ultimate when attempting to unlock the No Scope award?

Tags: achievements, smite

In patch 3.9 Janus can now achieve the **No Scope** award:

> As Janus hit at least two enemy gods with your ultimate at max distance.

Janus's ult appears to travel through the entire map.  It casts portals **[for the first 500 units](http://smite.gamepedia.com/Janus)**, but appears to do damage throughout its path.  I note that:

> Distance Scaling: 200% of your Magical Power at distance greater than 800.

...which suggests that it goes beyond 800 units (is that correct?).

I have been playing Arena, firing the ult from my fountain into the opposite minion portal (i.e. where my team's minions exit the map).  I have hit multiple enemies in this area.  This has not given me the award.

According to this **[question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/225821/how-large-is-a-smite-arena-map-in-units)** Arena is around 500 units long.  However, **[someone](https://www.trueachievements.com/a217319/no-scope-achievement.htm)** has unlocked it on Clash at what appears to be a smaller distance than my Arena efforts.

What actually counts as "max distance" for this award?

Comment: If there's no max range for it to deal damage, then the best map to try this on is probably Assault. Get Janus somehow, and when the map loads, immediately pump a level into the ult and fire while everyone is still buying items. That might be problematic since normal Assault is random pick. But, some MotD scenarios include picking gods on the Assault map, and if you play Assault often enough (it's the primary mode I play), you're bound to randomly get him or trade another player for him.

Comment: @Ellesedil - I managed to get a game with Janus on assault, but couldn't get this to work.  I think part of the problem is that the enemies are spread out too far, and you cannot get the angle to hit multiple gods at the start.  Even more frustrating is that I have hit multiple gods several times on clash from the same position as the linked video.  On Clash, I would stand just behind or to the side of the tower and fire through the jungle buff and into the gods on the opposite side.  I was seeing multiple numbers pop over the screen so would assume I was getting multiple hits.

Comment: So, I managed to get this achievement this past evening in Assault. The only issue is I'm not sure which usage of his ult triggered it for me as there wasn't an in-game notification on PC. I *did* use it immediately after I bought items, but I have no idea if I hit anyone. And there were a couple of other long-range attempts. If I had to guess, I think the "max distance" might be the 800 meter mark, but I have no way of verifying it right now.

Comment: @Ellesedil - I managed to get it by firing it from the fountain into the attack damage buff on Clash.  I've also been in a game whereby someone fired from the speed buff up towards the opposite attack damage buff, in conquest, and managed to get the award/achievement.  Maybe 800 units is correct.