# What is the range of the Wizard's Disintegrate spell in yards?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-wizard

What is the range of the Wizard's Disintegrate spell in yards?  (Assuming the [Entropy rune](https://us.battle.net/d3/en/class/wizard/active/disintegrate) is not in use, as that rune changes the range of the spell.)

**Research done**

From [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/66055/3354) with a screenshot showing the approximate on-screen ranges in yards, plus my own research:

[image: Disintegrate]

(Taken on a 1920x1080 monitor, 16:9 aspect ratio)

...I can tell that the Disintegrate range is "about 50 yards", but I'm interested in a more exact answer.

These sites do not currently provide an answer:

- https://us.battle.net/d3/en/class/wizard/active/disintegrate
- https://www.diablowiki.net/Disintegrate

**Reason for asking**

I'm interested in how much of the Disintegrate beam is eligible for damage increase via the [Power Hungry](https://us.battle.net/d3/en/class/wizard/passive/) passive, which increases damage to enemies 30+ yards away.

Comment: The thread on diablo.incgamers linked from the old answer lists Ray of Frost at 55 yards, and it does look like that for me from your screenshot, too. Probably the easiest way to test would be to grab yourself a Barbarian, stand on a waypoint together, let them leap away 50 yards and measure your ray against them :-)

Comment: You can use necromancer aura skills (frailty and devour) to get a visual indicator of yardage.  The base radius is 15 yards, which gives it a 30-yard diameter - exactly what your skill works off of.  Have the necromancer stand still, then move your character so you're exactly on the aura circle.  Then start Disintegrate aiming exactly at their model.  Any of the beam that is outside the necro aura on the other side is >30 yards.  If you take a screenshot you could probably get an exact yard measurement.

Answer (score 7):

According to this [wiki page](http://diablo.wikia.com/wiki/Disintegrate)(yes, I do tend to trust some text written on the internet by somebody that I do not know):

> Disintegrate conjures a limited-length **(50 yards)** beam that pierces through enemies and destructibles (but not any other obstacles).

So you were quite correct when you said that the range is *about 50 yards*